# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create

Tags: visual-studio, pthreads, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I started working on the port and got a good amount of our codebase to compile using your VS integration. I want to get everything up and running with the pepper api so I can debug any issues with the VS debugger.
Now I stumbled across some linker errors in your pthread library. I could reproduce it in the “hello_world_gles” sample. I just create a new thread using pthread_create and I get the following linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create
```

If I choose NaCl32 as target platform everything is working fine. I’ve added the “pthread.lib” file to the additional dependencies of the ppapi config. Do I need todo anything else?

Btw, is there any progress on the issue that the debugger is always attached to the wrong process when launching from VS?

Answer (score 1):

The pthread library we include for the PPAPI configuration is actually pthreads-win32 (http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) and can be found at pepper_XX\lib\win_x86_32_host\Debug\pthread.lib. I got it working by defining PTW32_STATIC_LIB before the “pthread.h” include.

I just ran a test using the VS Add-in on Chrome 33 with pepper_31 library and was able to make it work, with some manual fixes. I didn't have to make any changes to link pthread.lib, however. If you have NACL_SDK_ROOT in your system environment variables, then the add-in should add the proper include and library directories for you automatically.

Make sure you're running the latest version:

> naclsdk list -r
>   Bundles:
>    I: installed
>    *: update available

...
  I  vs_addin (dev) (r1568)
...

If your version is older, you can update by running:

> naclsdk update --force vs_addin
>   cd vs_addin
>   install